# Possible to add ASP .Net Identity classes to existing project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I have an existing ASP .Net web project (not MVC). In order to add ASP .Net Identity database tables i followed the instructions to create a user using this link http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

The tables have been created but is there a way to import all the required classes into my project so i could take advantage of the ready built classes/methods across my application rather than writing my own? If yes how?

I've read a ton of articles but not sure if this possible. When creating a new project with authentication selected it does contain these classes but I dont know if i should just copy and paste those classes into my project?

Appreciate any help/advice.

Comment: Do you mean the classes with your users/roles/claims and so on? What specific classes are not already in your project after following that article?

Comment: The link i followed only gave me a page to register a user (which created the tables required) and login. There were no other classes in my project to carry out operations such as reset a password, change password, lock account etc - unless i missed something out?

Comment: @Computer those MVC Views are auto generated by the bootstrapper for the the MVC project type. You'll have to write all the intervening display code yourself if you're not using the bootstrapper. You can then use the methods in the Identity class to do the required functions such as password reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most of what you are asking for has a combination of UI and identity framework parts, probably the easiest solution is to create a new mvc 5 site with visual studio 2013. This will create an AccountController and associated views to manage most of what you are talking about. To work this into an existing project, you can selectively include some of these files into your existing project. This at least did work for me where I was doing something similar for a VS 2012 solution.